# Snowflake - HASH_AGG Comparison (Normal vs Derived)

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

*Not sure if (Normal vs Derived) is the appropriate nomenclature.*

I have a table...

```
CREATE TABLE db_a.schema_a.table_a (
    COL_A NUMBER(2,0),
    COL_B NUMBER(2,0),
    COL_C NUMBER(2,0),
    COL_D NUMBER(2,0)
);
```

And I would like to compute the HASH_AGG value for `COL_A` and `COL_B`

A standard approach would be `SELECT HASH_AGG(COL_A, COL_B) FROM table_a;`

I need to solve for getting the same `HASH_AGG` value but through selecting the columns from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` or some other way that I'm not yet aware of.

My approach, but does not return the same `HASH_AGG` value as the example above...

```
SELECT HASH_AGG(
    SELECT LISTAGG(column_name, ',')
    FROM DB_A.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE table_schema = 'SCHEMA_A'
    AND table_name = 'TABLE_A'
    AND column_name NOT IN ('COL_C', 'COL_D')
)
FROM table_a;
```

I'm assuming `SELECT LISTAGG()` is not really returning what I think it does.  Or Snowflake doesn't interpret it how it prints to the screen.

Comment: LISTAGG returns a string not an array - so what I am guessing is being passed to HASH_AGG is a string containing all the column names separated by ',' and it is hashing that string. It is not querying the values in table_a columns and hashing those values

Comment: You'll probably need to write a Stored Proc to achieve what you want. This link should give you enough info to get you started: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Select-columns-based-on-condition-in-Snowflake-using-Information-Schema-and-Stored-Procedure